# Print thread id at breakpoint

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, gdb

I am debugging some C++ code. When I am paused at breakpoint, if I do `info thread`, gdb shows me a list of all the threads in my process, and puts an asterisk next to the thread under execution at breakpoint. Is there a gdb command which makes gdb tell you the thread id when at breakpoint?

I am doing `catch throw` and `catch catch`, to debug around the time an exception is thrown on thread 1. But, thread 2 is simultaneously also throwing and catching exceptions. Since, I am only interested in `throw` and `catch` on thread1, I plan to ask gdb for threadid, and script the breakpoint to continue if threadid is 2.

```
(gdb) catch throw
Catchpoint 7 (throw)
(gdb) catch catch
Catchpoint 8 (catch) 
(gdb) command 8
> if threadid == 2
>      c
> end
```

Can you please show me how to write this line `if threadid == 2`?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [built-in `$_thread` convenience variable](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html):

> The debugger convenience variables `$_thread` and `$_gthread` contain,
>   respectively, the per-inferior thread number and the global thread
>   number of the current thread. You may find this useful in writing
>   breakpoint conditional expressions, command scripts, and so forth. See
>   Convenience Variables, for general information on convenience
>   variables.

```
catch catch if $_thread == 1
```

Using the [Python API](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads-In-Python.html):

> — Function: gdb.selected_thread () This function returns the thread
>   object for the selected thread. If there is no selected thread, this
>   will return None.

```
catch catch
command
  python
    if gdb.selected_thread() != 1:
      gdb.execute('continue');
  end
end
```

Generally speaking, when GDB lacks a feature, it's very unlikely you cannot implement it using the Python API since it allows you to explore your running program and context.

Comment: That `catch catch` line won't actually work, as `python` isn't a valid part of an expression like that.

Comment: @TomTromey That's right. I've modified the answer. Thanks.